# VBA - Moving large number of records - some records missing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set of around 1500 sales records. I have written a macro, which would create product category specific work books, which would have an individual work sheet for each product in the product category.

The macro is working as expected, but I have found out that it is consistently ignoring some products. I put debug statements to see if I am getting zero records when I filter based on the product code (since I use this selection to paste the records to a separate work sheet). The selection seems to be working fine, as I get the number of rows selected.

A pattern I saw was that the product codes which were having zero records were generally the first ones or the last ones to get processed before or after a file operation (either I open a category specific work book, or I am closing a work book). But even here, the table header was copied to the individual work sheet. Only the data rows were getting ignored.

Is there a chance where the macro is processing the records too fast, while there is some time lag in doing File I/O operations (which makes a few records to get ignored)?

I am attaching the code, which I have used for looping
'loop through each row and get the product id and the category (Ann & Bnn).

```
 '  Dim catWorkBook As Workbook
    oProductCat = "0" 'the initial value set as 0, which would NEVER be a category
    With wkScrap 'this is a rough sheet which has the product items and categories
        For i = 2 To lProdRow
            cProductCode = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            cProductCat = .Cells(i, 2).Value

            'FILE OPEN: will need to open a category specific .xls file
            If (StrComp(cProductCat, oProductCat) <> 0) Then
                'save the existing workbook
                FileIO.CloseExcelFile oProductCat, catWorkBook

                Set catWorkBook = Nothing 'clear all traces of the old worksheet
                Set catWorkBook = CreateBlankWorkBook()
                oProductCat = cProductCat
            End If

            'COPY DATA: Filtering on product code, and then moving it into a new
            'worksheet
            CopyCategoryToWorksheet cProductCode, catWorkBook

            If i = lProdRow Then
                'we are at the end of the loop. Proceed to close the current
                'workbook
                FileIO.CloseExcelFile oProductCat, catWorkBook
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Here is the function which does the actual copying

```
Private Sub CopyCategoryToWorksheet(prodCode As String, catWkBook As Workbook)
    'check for a meaningful prod code
    If (Trim(prodCode & vbNullString) = vbNullString) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wkRData As Worksheet
    Dim rRData As Range
    Dim rDataMaxRows As Integer
    Set wkRData = SalesReport.Sheet1

    'We know that we have to create a work sheet for this product code.
    'Let us do that first.
    Dim prodCatSheet As Worksheet
    catWkBook.Activate
    Set prodCatSheet = catWkBook.Sheets.Add(After:=catWkBook.Sheets(catWkBook.Sheets.Count))
    prodCatSheet.Name = prodCode

    wkRData.Activate 'for this sub routine, all processing is happening on the raw data sheet
    rDataMaxRows = Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rRData = Range("A1:H" & rDataMaxRows)
    rRData.AutoFilter 3, Criteria1:="=" & Trim(prodCode)
    rRData.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'activate the newly created sheet, and paste all the selected rows there
    prodCatSheet.Activate
    prodCatSheet.PasteSpecial

    Set wkRData = Nothing 'just clear some memory
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us your code. Do you have a loop going on? If so, is there a DoEvents in there? Have you tried introducing Application.Wait in at points? Tbh, what have you tried?

Comment: I would have to guess that the issue **isn't** caused by "processing the records too fast" but can't be 100% sure without seeing your code.

Comment: I'd put breaks in just before you open and close a file and look at what your criteria is. I suspect you're moving a pointer twice n(once before you open and once after perhaps?) and skipping a cell

Comment: Please find the code which I use for looping..

Comment: I have added the code block which does the processing.